# How to access grub after installing Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, hp

I followed the following video to install ubuntu: https://youtu.be/MSVV_EoApdo

After finishing installing Ubuntu, I get a message asking me to reboot. I removed by USB then pressed reboot. That took me to a black screen asking me to remove the installation medium then reboot. I held the power key down until the laptop shut down then powered it on again. But I am automatically sent to windows booter.

I tried using the bcdedit /set command and to go to bios menu to change OS boot loader to grub, but grub isnt visible anywhere there.

My laptop is an hp pavilion with windows 10 already installed.

How do I make my laptop to boot using grub by default?

Comment: You won't find the option "grub" in your BIOS/EFI settings. What are the options it shows you to boot?

Comment: @guillermochamorro shows a list with "os boot loader", "usb diskette", and such. I tried pressing enter when I have "os boot loader" as I saw some people suggest that grub might be under it in a menu, but no such menu opened.

Comment: If you can read, you'd better go with official documentation https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot